# TFS WIT - Skip State if a field contains a specific value

Tags: tfs, state, transition

I am working on a custom work item template for TFS 2012. Currently "System.State" has 3 states "Active", "Approved", "Completed", in order to select "Completed", the System.State has to be set to "Approved". However, there are certain scenarios where the template should skip "Approved" and transition from "Active" to "Completed". I want to allow the user to skip approved if another field ("Sample.Field") equals "Skip". I have tried adding the following WHEN rule but it doesn't work. Has anyone done this before or have a work around? Thanks,

```
<FieldDefinition name="State" refname="System.State" type="String" reportable="dimension">
  <WHEN field="Sample.Field" value="Skip;">
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="Active" />
      <LISTITEM value="Completed" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  </WHEN> 
</FieldDefinition>
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be done in the `<TRANSITION>` statement. But I don't think it is possible to condition a transition on states; the only allowed ones are **for** and **not** user groups.  The sub-statements control behavior of fields for the transition. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337653.aspx.